# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

This is 2nd question following 1st question at
[PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "nfs-pv-provisioning-demo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47335939/persistentvolumeclaim-is-not-bound-nfs-pv-provisioning-demo)

I am setting up a kubernetes lab using one node only and learning to setup kubernetes nfs. I am following kubernetes nfs example step by step from the following link: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs

Based on feedback provided by 'helmbert', I modified the content of 
https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/provisioner/nfs-server-gce-pv.yaml

It works and I don't see the event "PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: “nfs-pv-provisioning-demo”" anymore.

```
$ cat nfs-server-local-pv01.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv01
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/tmp/data01"


$ cat nfs-server-local-pvc01.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv-provisioning-demo
  labels:
    demo: nfs-pv-provisioning
spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi


$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv01      10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                      4s


$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                       STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs-pv-provisioning-demo   Bound     pv01      10Gi       RWO                           2m



$ kubectl get pod
NAME                READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-server-nlzlv    1/1       Running             0          1h


$ kubectl describe pods nfs-server-nlzlv
Name:           nfs-server-nlzlv
Namespace:      default
Node:           lab-kube-06/10.0.0.6
Start Time:     Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:32:21 +0000
Labels:         role=nfs-server
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"nfs-server","uid":"b1b00292-cef2-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04eb...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.32.0.3
Created By:     ReplicationController/nfs-server
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/nfs-server
Containers:
  nfs-server:
    Container ID:   docker://1ea76052920d4560557cfb5e5bfc9f8efc3af5f13c086530bd4e0aded201955a
    Image:          gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs@sha256:83ba87be13a6f74361601c8614527e186ca67f49091e2d0d4ae8a8da67c403ee
    Ports:          2049/TCP, 20048/TCP, 111/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 21 Nov 2017 19:32:43 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /exports from mypvc (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-grgdz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          True
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  mypvc:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  nfs-pv-provisioning-demo
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-grgdz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-grgdz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

I continued the rest of steps and reached the "Setup the fake backend" section and ran the following command:

```
$ kubectl create -f examples/volumes/nfs/nfs-busybox-rc.yaml
```

I see status 'ContainerCreating' and never change to 'Running' for both nfs-busybox pods. Is this because the container image is for Google Cloud as shown in the yaml?

https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-server-rc.yaml

```
  containers:
  - name: nfs-server
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/volume-nfs:0.8
    ports:
      - name: nfs
        containerPort: 2049
      - name: mountd
        containerPort: 20048
      - name: rpcbind
        containerPort: 111
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /exports
        name: mypvc
```

Do I have to replace that 'image' line to something else because I don't use Google Cloud for this lab? I only have a single node in my lab. Do I have to rewrite the definition of 'containers' above? What should I replace the 'image' line with? Do I need to download dockerized 'nfs image' from somewhere?

```
$ kubectl describe pvc nfs
Name:          nfs
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Bound
Volume:        nfs
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed=yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
Capacity:      1Mi
Access Modes:  RWX
Events:        <none>


$ kubectl describe pv nfs
Name:            nfs
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller=yes
StorageClass:
Status:          Bound
Claim:           default/nfs
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWX
Capacity:        1Mi
Message:
Source:
    Type:      NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:    10.111.29.157
    Path:      /
    ReadOnly:  false
Events:        <none>


$ kubectl get rc
NAME          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
nfs-busybox   2         2         0         25s
nfs-server    1         1         1         1h


$ kubectl get pod
NAME                READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nfs-busybox-lmgtx   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          3m
nfs-busybox-xn9vz   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          3m
nfs-server-nlzlv    1/1       Running             0          1h


$ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      20m
nfs-server   ClusterIP   10.111.29.157   <none>        2049/TCP,20048/TCP,111/TCP   9s


$ kubectl describe services nfs-server
Name:              nfs-server
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          role=nfs-server
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.111.29.157
Port:              nfs  2049/TCP
TargetPort:        2049/TCP
Endpoints:         10.32.0.3:2049
Port:              mountd  20048/TCP
TargetPort:        20048/TCP
Endpoints:         10.32.0.3:20048
Port:              rpcbind  111/TCP
TargetPort:        111/TCP
Endpoints:         10.32.0.3:111
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

$ kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                              STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
nfs       1Mi        RWX            Retain           Bound     default/nfs                                                 38m
pv01      10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound     default/nfs-pv-provisioning-demo                            1h
```

I see repeating events - MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32

```
    $ kubectl describe pod nfs-busybox-lmgtx
Name:           nfs-busybox-lmgtx
Namespace:      default
Node:           lab-kube-06/10.0.0.6
Start Time:     Tue, 21 Nov 2017 20:39:35 +0000
Labels:         name=nfs-busybox
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"nfs-busybox","uid":"15d683c2-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04e...
Status:         Pending
IP:
Created By:     ReplicationController/nfs-busybox
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/nfs-busybox
Containers:
  busybox:
    Container ID:
    Image:         busybox
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      while true; do date > /mnt/index.html; hostname >> /mnt/index.html; sleep $(($RANDOM % 5 + 5)); done
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /mnt from nfs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-grgdz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  nfs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  nfs
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-grgdz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-grgdz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s

Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age   From                  Message
  ----     ------                 ----  ----                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled              17m   default-scheduler     Successfully assigned nfs-busybox-lmgtx to lab-kube-06
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  17m   kubelet, lab-kube-06  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-grgdz"
  Warning  FailedMount            17m   kubelet, lab-kube-06  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/15d8d6d6-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs --scope -- mount -t nfs 10.111.29.157:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/15d8d6d6-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs
Output: Running scope as unit run-43641.scope.
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 10.111.29.157:/,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.

  Warning  FailedMount  9m (x4 over 15m)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  Unable to mount volumes for pod "nfs-busybox-lmgtx_default(15d8d6d6-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"nfs-busybox-lmgtx". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[nfs]
  Warning  FailedMount  4m (x8 over 15m)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  (combined from similar events): Unable to mount volumes for pod "nfs-busybox-lmgtx_default(15d8d6d6-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"nfs-busybox-lmgtx". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[nfs]
  Warning  FailedSync   2m (x7 over 15m)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  Error syncing pod



$ kubectl describe pod nfs-busybox-xn9vz
Name:           nfs-busybox-xn9vz
Namespace:      default
Node:           lab-kube-06/10.0.0.6
Start Time:     Tue, 21 Nov 2017 20:39:35 +0000
Labels:         name=nfs-busybox
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"nfs-busybox","uid":"15d683c2-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04e...
Status:         Pending
IP:
Created By:     ReplicationController/nfs-busybox
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/nfs-busybox
Containers:
  busybox:
    Container ID:
    Image:         busybox
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      while true; do date > /mnt/index.html; hostname >> /mnt/index.html; sleep $(($RANDOM % 5 + 5)); done
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /mnt from nfs (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-grgdz (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  nfs:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  nfs
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-grgdz:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-grgdz
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age               From                  Message
  ----     ------       ----              ----                  -------
  Warning  FailedMount  59m (x6 over 1h)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  Unable to mount volumes for pod "nfs-busybox-xn9vz_default(15d7fb5e-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "default"/"nfs-busybox-xn9vz". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[nfs]
  Warning  FailedMount  7m (x32 over 1h)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  (combined from similar events): MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/15d7fb5e-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs --scope -- mount -t nfs 10.111.29.157:/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/15d7fb5e-cefc-11e7-8ed3-000d3a04ebcd/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs
Output: Running scope as unit run-59365.scope.
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 10.111.29.157:/,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
  Warning  FailedSync  2m (x31 over 1h)  kubelet, lab-kube-06  Error syncing pod
```

Comment: Does your NFS disk have a file system? I'd format the disk and re-create the file system with`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX` (linux)

Comment: The NFS disk is on the same box, since it is a one box lab. It is running Redhat 7.4. The folder is '/tmp/data01' and it is on /dev/sda2 (linux).

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem,

```
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
```

directly on the nodes fixed it for ubuntu 18.04 server.

Comment: how you run this command on node ? you mean by exec-ing into nfs server pod ?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: That ^ link describes for running commands inside a container. But the answers here are about running commands on node. I am using docker-for-desktop.

Answer (score 6):

NFS server running on AWS EC2.
My pod was stuck in ContainerCreating state

I was facing this issue because of the Kubernetes cluster node CIDR range was not present in the inbound rule of Security Group of my AWS EC2 instance(where my NFS server was running )

Solution:
Added my Kubernetes cluser Node CIDR range to inbound rule of Security Group.

[image]

Comment: Can you share step by step where to click, I'm a little noobie in AWS IAM and Security Groups, if you have time.

Comment: @PhilipPetrov You have to update Security Group attached to Ec2 instance where your NFS is running. Inside Security Group go to inbound rules and add you cluster CIDR and port

Answer (score 5):

Installed the following nfs libraries on node machine of **CentOS** worked for me.

> yum install -y nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib

Answer (score 4):

Installing the nfs-common library in ubuntu worked for me.

Comment: In Ubuntu container? Or on the nodes?

Comment: Directly on the nodes.